# Organize data into appropriate columns using python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am using vertica_python to pull data from the database. The column that I pull comes as a string in the following format:

```
[{"id":0,"prediction_type":"CONV_PROBABILITY","calibration_factor":0.906556,"inte   cept":-2.410414,"advMatchTypeId":-0.239877,"atsId":-0.135568,"deviceTypeId":0.439130,"dmaCode":-0.251728,"keywordId":0.442240}]
```

I then split and parse this sting and load it into excel in the following format, each index being a cell:

```
prediction_type CONV_PROBABILIT calibration_factor  0.90655 intercept   -2.41041    advMatchTypeId  -0.23987    atsId   1.44701 deviceTypeId    0.19701 dmaCode -0.69982    keywordId   0.44224
```

Here's my problem.The string doesn't have a definite format, meaning, that sometimes I be missing some features from the string, messing up my formatting. Here's an example:

```
intercept   -2.41041    advMatchTypeId  -0.23987    deviceTypeId    0.37839 dmaCode -0.53552    keywordId   0.44224     
intercept   -2.41041    advMatchTypeId  -0.23987    atsId   0.80708 deviceTypeId    -0.19573    dmaCode -0.69982    keywordId   0.44224
```

How can I retain formatting the way I want and have the above example come out looking like this instead:

```
intercept   -2.41041    advMatchTypeId  -0.23987                     deviceTypeId   0.37839     dmaCode -0.53552    keywordId   0.44224
intercept   -2.41041    advMatchTypeId  -0.23987    atsId   0.80708  deviceTypeId   -0.19573    dmaCode -0.69982    keywordId   0.44224
```

This is the code I am using:

```
data_all = cur.fetchall()

for i in range(len(data_all)):
    col = 0
    data_one = ''.join(data_all[i])
    raw_coef = data_one.split(',')[1:len(data_all)]
    for j in range(len(raw_coef)):
        raw = ''.join(raw_coef[j])
        raw = re.sub('"|}|{|[|]|', '', raw)[:-1]
        raw = raw.split(":")
        for k in range(len(raw)):
            worksheet.write(i, col, raw[k], align_left)
            feature.append(raw[0]) # for unique values
            col+=1
```

My query:

```
cur.execute(
"""
select MODEL_COEF
from

dcf_funnel.ADV_BIDDER_PRICING_LOG
where MODEL_ID = 8960
and DATE(AMP_QUERY_TIMESTAMP) = '11-02-2016'
"""
)
```

Comment: Please add the code you currently use to split the data up and organise it to write to Excel.

Comment: That's better, thanks. You are not getting a string back, you're getting a list that contains a dictionary. You appear to be be converting it to a string and then trying to use regex to split it all back up again. I need to check something with `cursor` properties and then I will try put something together

Comment: This string comes from a single column, if I understand your comment correctly.

Comment: It is not a string at all. It's a valid Python data structure (a `list` containing a `dictionary`). It only becomes a string when you do `''.join()`. You seem to be shooting yourself in the foot with that part. I normally use `SQLite` which returns tuples, but I can't think of any reason a query would ever return a `string` that you have to chop up with regex.

Comment: Alright, in any case, It doesn't return in a set format. So how can I go through the list so that everything is lined up like in my questions' last example ?

Comment: That is what I'm looking into now for you. But, without trying to sound too critical, "in any case" isn't really the correct response. You _absolutely_ need to be able to recognise `dict` and `list` in Python to be able to do anything useful. You've made this task near impossible for yourself without knowing that.

Comment: Can you do me a favour please? Rather than me try validate my approach in SQLite... immediately after you do `cur.fetchall()` could you give me the result of `headers = [header[0] for header in cur.description]`? I don't know if all variations of SQL work exactly the same way

Comment: Why dont you keep track of master column list, So when you parse the data if a columns is missing then keep it empty and if there is a new column then update the master column list as well.

Comment: How committed are you to having the column names repeated as a column? The normal way to do this is to have the column header at the top and just the values in the columns. In fact, if you're using Excel for the downstream analysis, this format will also make it easier to do pivot tables and filter.

Comment: @roganjosh yes absolutely, I didn't mean to say that in a disrespectful way. I will definitely learn that asap. I am trying to pull the result now.

Comment: @saurabhbaid I apologize I am not sure what you mean by that, do you happen to have an example?

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I'd take that approach if you think its easier. Any tip on how to structure it that way?

Comment: @opamp see my answer below. This is kind of the way tools want to work. It used to be called normalisation, now it's called [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: @roganjosh I get `['MODEL_COEF']` as result of running your command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip all your parsing and use pandas:

```
import pandas
```

This will read your query result into a DataFrame if it is already a list of dicts in Python.

```
data_all_list = [{"id":0,"prediction_type":"CONV_PROBABILITY","calibration_factor":0.906556,"intercept":-2.410414,"advMatchTypeId":-0.239877,"atsId":-0.135568,"deviceTypeId":0.439130,"dmaCode":-0.251728,"keywordId":0.442240}]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data_all_list)
```

If you really have string, you can just use `read_json`:

```
data_all_str = """[{"id":0,"prediction_type":"CONV_PROBABILITY","calibration_factor":0.906556,"intercept":-2.410414,"advMatchTypeId":-0.239877,"atsId":-0.135568,"deviceTypeId":0.439130,"dmaCode":-0.251728,"keywordId":0.442240}]"""
df = pandas.read_json(data_all_str)
```

Further thought has led me to understand that your `data_all` is actually a list of lists of dicts, something like this:

```
data_all_lol = [data_all_list, data_all_list]
```

In this case, you need to concatenate the lists before passing to DataFrame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(sum(data_all_lol, []))
```

This will write it in the normal headers + values format:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv') # you can also use to_excel
```

If your final goal is just to obtain the means of all the features, pandas can do that straight away, with an arbitrary number of columns, handling missing values correctly:

```
df.mean()
```

Gives

```
advMatchTypeId       -0.239877
atsId                -0.135568
calibration_factor    0.906556
deviceTypeId          0.439130
dmaCode              -0.251728
id                    0.000000
intercept            -2.410414
keywordId             0.442240
```

**Note about ambiguity**

In the OP it is hard to know the type of `data_all` because the snippet you show appears like a list of dicts in literal syntax, but you say "The column that I pull comes as a string".

Notice the difference between the way the inputs are represented in the following IPython session:

```
In [15]: data_all_str
Out[15]: '[{"id":0,"prediction_type":"CONV_PROBABILITY","calibration_factor":0.906556,"intercept":-2.410414,"advMatchTypeId":-0.239877,"atsId":-0.135568,"deviceTypeId":0.439130,"dmaCode":-0.251728,"keywordId":0.442240}]'

In [16]: data_all_list
Out[16]:
[{'advMatchTypeId': -0.239877,
  'atsId': -0.135568,
  'calibration_factor': 0.906556,
  'deviceTypeId': 0.43913,
  'dmaCode': -0.251728,
  'id': 0,
  'intercept': -2.410414,
  'keywordId': 0.44224,
  'prediction_type': 'CONV_PROBABILITY'}]
```

Comment: Thank you! But this will put the whole string into a single cell. I need to be able to parse it in order to get a description of the feature and average value. Therefore, I would like to have each cell contain a unique feature and its value

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to read the data from a json-compliant string, although it wasn't clear that you really have a string rather than a list of dicts.

Comment: @opamp Aha, now I see what you mean based on your last comment to me. Your very first line of code should have looked like `"""[{"id":0,"prediction_type":"CONV_PROBABILITY","calibration_factor":0.906556,"inte   cept":-2.410414,"advMatchTypeId":-0.239877,"atsId":-0.135568,"deviceTypeId":0.439130,"dmaCode":-0.251728,"keywordId":0.442240}]"""`. You really were getting a string of actual data structures, but you reported it as an actual list suggesting that you were misusing the term `string`. This answer is probably correct for you.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon the result you got is amazing. I believe I am confusing everyone and myself misusing words like string, list, dict. I will look into it asap. But in order to accomplish the result you got did you use `df = pandas.read_json(data_all)` or `df = pandas.DataFrame(data_all)`. I get an error when using `read_json` saying a string is expected.

Comment: Use the one that works for you. If the result of the query is a list of dicts the DataFrame one will work.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I'd love to the get the same result as you but all I get is: `Series([], dtype: float64)` do I have to go line by line?

Comment: It seems from the docs for vertica python you may have to use `cur = connection.cursor('dict')` to get the results in a dictionary. But I'm having a really hard time understanding your outputs. For either of the realistic interpretations of what `data_all` contains, my code should work.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon yes data_all contains exactly what my first snippet shows in the questions. But when trying to get the mean I get `Series([], dtype: float64)` instead of the result that you got.

Comment: @opamp I've updated my answer to include the sample data as I was using it to show what input I used to obtain my result. You need to update your question to remove the ambiguity about what is in `data_all` for us to help your any further. For instance, it would help a lot to paste the results of `repr(all_data)` and `type(all_data)`

Comment: @opamp I think I've figured out how your data comes because of the result you got for the mean above. See my updated answer with the `sum` in.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon thank you so much for figuring it out! This is amazing! When I pull the data it comes as a list, not string as I originally indicated. I then convert the list to a string and load it into df. Everything seems to be working perfectly. `fetch_all = cur.fetchall()
for i in range(len(fetch_all)):
 data = ''.join(fetch_all[i])
 df = pd.read_json(data)` I apologize for the initial confusion. Thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127384/discussion-between-chthonicdaemon-and-opamp).